# How to build QGIS on CentOS?

Tags: qgis, installation, centos

I'm trying to install QGIS, without success. I install all dependencies, but the compilation still sucks.

My compilation log :

```
[root@localhost build]# cmake ..
-- QGIS version: 2.4.0 Chugiak (20400)
-- Could not find GRASS
-- Found GEOS: /usr/lib64/libgeos_c.so
-- Found GDAL: /usr/lib64/libgdal.so (1.11.0)
-- Found Expat: /lib64/libexpat.so
-- Found Spatialindex: /usr/local/lib/libspatialindex.so
-- Found Sqlite3: /usr/lib64/libsqlite3.so
-- Found PostgreSQL: /usr/lib64/libpq.so
-- Found SpatiaLite: /usr/lib64/libspatialite.so
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:205 (MESSAGE):
  Some dependencies were not found!


-- Found Qt version: 4.8.5
-- Touch support disabled
-- Pedantic compiler settings enabled
-- Found Python executable: /bin/python
-- Found Python version: 2.7.5
-- Found Python library: /usr/lib64/libpython2.7.so
-- Found SIP version: 4.14.6
-- Found PyQt4 version: 4.10.1
-- Found QScintilla2 PyQt4 module: qsci_version_str:

-- Found GSL: -lgsl -lgslcblas -lm
-- txt2tags not found - disabled
-- Ctest Binary Directory  set to: /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/build/output/bin
CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND.
Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the CMake files:
PROJ_INCLUDE_DIR
   used as include directory in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/src/core
   used as include directory in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/src/analysis
   used as include directory in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/src/analysis/network
   used as include directory in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/src/analysis/network
   used as include directory in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/src/crssync
   used as include directory in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/src/crssync
   used as include directory in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/src/app
   used as include directory in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/src/app
   used as include directory in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/src/app
   used as include directory in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/tests/src/core
   used as include directory in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/tests/src/core
   used as include directory in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/tests/src/core
   used as include directory in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/tests/src/core
   used as include directory in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/tests/src/core
   used as include directory in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/tests/src/core
   used as include directory in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/tests/src/core
   used as include directory in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/tests/src/core
   used as include directory in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/tests/src/core
   used as include directory in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/tests/src/core
   used as include directory in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/tests/src/core
   used as include directory in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/tests/src/core
   used as include directory in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/tests/src/core
   used as include directory in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/tests/src/core
   used as include directory in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/tests/src/core
   used as include directory in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/tests/src/core
   used as include directory in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/tests/src/core
   used as include directory in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/tests/src/core
   used as include directory in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/tests/src/core
   used as include directory in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/tests/src/core
   used as include directory in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/tests/src/core
   used as include directory in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/tests/src/core
   used as include directory in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/tests/src/core
   used as include directory in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/tests/src/core
   used as include directory in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/tests/src/core
   used as include directory in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/tests/src/core
   used as include directory in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/tests/src/core
   used as include directory in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/tests/src/core
   used as include directory in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/tests/src/core
   used as include directory in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/tests/src/core
   used as include directory in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/tests/src/core
   used as include directory in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/tests/src/core
   used as include directory in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/tests/src/core
   used as include directory in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/tests/src/core
   used as include directory in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/tests/src/core
   used as include directory in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/tests/src/core
   used as include directory in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/tests/src/core
   used as include directory in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/tests/src/core
   used as include directory in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/tests/src/core
   used as include directory in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/tests/src/core
   used as include directory in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/tests/src/core
   used as include directory in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/tests/src/core
   used as include directory in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/tests/src/core
   used as include directory in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/tests/src/core
   used as include directory in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/tests/src/core
   used as include directory in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/tests/src/core
   used as include directory in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/tests/src/core
   used as include directory in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/tests/src/core
   used as include directory in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/tests/src/core
   used as include directory in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/tests/src/core
   used as include directory in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/tests/src/core
   used as include directory in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/tests/src/core
   used as include directory in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/tests/src/core
   used as include directory in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/tests/src/core
   used as include directory in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/tests/src/core
   used as include directory in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/tests/src/core
   used as include directory in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/tests/src/core
   used as include directory in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/tests/src/core
   used as include directory in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/tests/src/core
   used as include directory in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/tests/src/core
   used as include directory in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/tests/src/core
   used as include directory in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/tests/src/core
   used as include directory in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/tests/src/core
   used as include directory in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/tests/src/core
   used as include directory in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/tests/src/core
   used as include directory in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/tests/src/core
   used as include directory in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/tests/src/core
   used as include directory in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/tests/src/core
   used as include directory in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/tests/src/core
   used as include directory in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/tests/src/core
   used as include directory in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/tests/src/core
   used as include directory in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/tests/src/core
   used as include directory in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/tests/src/core
   used as include directory in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/tests/src/core
   used as include directory in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/tests/src/core
   used as include directory in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/tests/src/core
   used as include directory in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/tests/src/core
   used as include directory in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/tests/src/core
   used as include directory in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/tests/src/core
   used as include directory in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/tests/src/core
   used as include directory in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/tests/src/core
   used as include directory in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/tests/src/core
   used as include directory in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/tests/src/core
   used as include directory in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/tests/src/core
   used as include directory in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/tests/src/core
   used as include directory in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/tests/src/core
   used as include directory in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/tests/src/core
   used as include directory in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/tests/src/core
   used as include directory in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/tests/src/core
   used as include directory in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/tests/src/core
   used as include directory in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/tests/src/gui
   used as include directory in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/tests/src/gui
   used as include directory in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/tests/src/gui
   used as include directory in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/tests/src/gui
   used as include directory in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/tests/src/gui
   used as include directory in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/tests/src/gui
   used as include directory in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/tests/src/gui
   used as include directory in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/tests/src/gui
   used as include directory in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/tests/src/gui
   used as include directory in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/tests/src/gui
   used as include directory in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/tests/src/gui
   used as include directory in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/tests/src/gui
   used as include directory in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/tests/src/analysis
   used as include directory in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/tests/src/analysis
   used as include directory in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/tests/src/analysis
   used as include directory in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/tests/src/analysis
   used as include directory in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/tests/src/analysis
   used as include directory in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/tests/src/analysis
   used as include directory in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/tests/src/providers
   used as include directory in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/tests/src/providers
   used as include directory in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/tests/src/app
   used as include directory in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/tests/src/app
PROJ_LIBRARY
    linked by target "qgis_core" in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/src/core
    linked by target "crssync" in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/src/crssync
    linked by target "qgis_applicationtest" in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/tests/src/core
    linked by target "qgis_atlascompositiontest" in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/tests/src/core
    linked by target "qgis_blendmodestest" in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/tests/src/core
    linked by target "qgis_clippertest" in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/tests/src/core
    linked by target "qgis_composereffectstest" in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/tests/src/core
    linked by target "qgis_composerhtmltest" in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/tests/src/core
    linked by target "qgis_composerlabeltest" in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/tests/src/core
    linked by target "qgis_composermaptest" in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/tests/src/core
    linked by target "qgis_composerpapertest" in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/tests/src/core
    linked by target "qgis_composerpicturetest" in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/tests/src/core
    linked by target "qgis_composerrotationtest" in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/tests/src/core
    linked by target "qgis_composerscalebartest" in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/tests/src/core
    linked by target "qgis_composershapestest" in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/tests/src/core
    linked by target "qgis_composertabletest" in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/tests/src/core
    linked by target "qgis_contrastenhancementtest" in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/tests/src/core
    linked by target "qgis_coordinatereferencesystemtest" in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/tests/src/core
    linked by target "qgis_dataitemtest" in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/tests/src/core
    linked by target "qgis_diagramexpressiontest" in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/tests/src/core
    linked by target "qgis_diagramtest" in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/tests/src/core
    linked by target "qgis_distanceareatest" in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/tests/src/core
    linked by target "qgis_expressiontest" in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/tests/src/core
    linked by target "qgis_filewritertest" in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/tests/src/core
    linked by target "qgis_geometrytest" in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/tests/src/core
    linked by target "qgis_gradienttest" in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/tests/src/core
    linked by target "qgis_invertedpolygontest" in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/tests/src/core
    linked by target "qgis_maplayertest" in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/tests/src/core
    linked by target "qgis_maprenderertest" in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/tests/src/core
    linked by target "qgis_ogcutilstest" in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/tests/src/core
    linked by target "qgis_pointtest" in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/tests/src/core
    linked by target "qgis_projecttest" in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/tests/src/core
    linked by target "qgis_rasterfilewritertest" in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/tests/src/core
    linked by target "qgis_rasterlayertest" in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/tests/src/core
    linked by target "qgis_rastersublayertest" in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/tests/src/core
    linked by target "qgis_rectangletest" in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/tests/src/core
    linked by target "qgis_regression1141" in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/tests/src/core
    linked by target "qgis_regression992" in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/tests/src/core
    linked by target "qgis_rendererstest" in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/tests/src/core
    linked by target "qgis_rulebasedrenderertest" in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/tests/src/core
    linked by target "qgis_shapebursttest" in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/tests/src/core
    linked by target "qgis_spatialindextest" in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/tests/src/core
    linked by target "qgis_stylev2test" in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/tests/src/core
    linked by target "qgis_vectordataprovidertest" in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/tests/src/core
    linked by target "qgis_vectorlayercachetest" in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/tests/src/core
    linked by target "qgis_vectorlayertest" in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/tests/src/core
    linked by target "qgis_ziplayertest" in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/tests/src/core
    linked by target "qgis_dualviewtest" in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/tests/src/gui
    linked by target "qgis_mapcanvastest" in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/tests/src/gui
    linked by target "qgis_projectionissues" in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/tests/src/gui
    linked by target "qgis_rubberbandtest" in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/tests/src/gui
    linked by target "qgis_scalecombobox" in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/tests/src/gui
    linked by target "qgis_zoomtest" in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/tests/src/gui
    linked by target "qgis_wcsprovidertest" in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/tests/src/providers
    linked by target "qgis_qgisappclipboard" in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/tests/src/app
QWT_INCLUDE_DIR
   used as include directory in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/src/gui
   used as include directory in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/src/app
   used as include directory in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/src/app
   used as include directory in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/src/app
   used as include directory in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/src/plugins/georeferencer
   used as include directory in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/python
   used as include directory in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/python
   used as include directory in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/python
   used as include directory in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/python
   used as include directory in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/python
   used as include directory in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/python
   used as include directory in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/python
   used as include directory in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/python
   used as include directory in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/python
   used as include directory in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/python
   used as include directory in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/python
   used as include directory in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/python
   used as include directory in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/python
   used as include directory in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/python
   used as include directory in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/python
   used as include directory in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/tests/src/gui
   used as include directory in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/tests/src/gui
   used as include directory in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/tests/src/gui
   used as include directory in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/tests/src/gui
   used as include directory in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/tests/src/gui
   used as include directory in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/tests/src/gui
   used as include directory in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/tests/src/gui
   used as include directory in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/tests/src/gui
   used as include directory in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/tests/src/gui
   used as include directory in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/tests/src/gui
   used as include directory in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/tests/src/gui
   used as include directory in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/tests/src/gui
QWT_LIBRARY
    linked by target "qgis_gui" in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/src/gui
    linked by target "qgis" in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/src/app
    linked by target "qgis_app" in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/src/app
    linked by target "qgis_dualviewtest" in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/tests/src/gui
    linked by target "qgis_mapcanvastest" in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/tests/src/gui
    linked by target "qgis_projectionissues" in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/tests/src/gui
    linked by target "qgis_rubberbandtest" in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/tests/src/gui
    linked by target "qgis_scalecombobox" in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/tests/src/gui
    linked by target "qgis_zoomtest" in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/tests/src/gui
    linked by target "qgis_qgisappclipboard" in directory /home/user/workspace/Delivery/console/cots/qgis-2.4.0/tests/src/app

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

I tried to install GRASS:

```
yum install grass grass-devel qgis-grass
```

But without success (I don't know i problem come from here ...)

Comment: Can you update your question with the error you get from trying to install GRASS? Also looks like you need to install Proj4 or set the include dir with cmake. Could you try installing qwt and qwtpolar as well?